# i need help fixing this error

Tags: package-management, uninstall, spotify

```
E: Type 'http://repository.spotify.com' is not known on line 7 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type 'http://repository.spotify.com' is not known on line 7 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

i dont know how to open the source list please use explicit detail

Comment: *"i dont know how to open the source list"* - Have you tried `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

Answer (score 0):

In `terminal`...

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

to review the contents of this file.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

to edit this file... if you understand what the error is. Normally this file only contains `deb` statements. **If you're not sure, then don't touch this file**, but show us the output of the cat command by editing that information into your original question.